# filterd queryset for foreginkey

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Employee has 2 types sales and normal employee,
in sales forms i want to display only sales employee

Comment: We would really need to see what code you've come up with so far to be able to help you. Apart from that it's even not the way you should ask questions here. Please have a look at the help section https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BranchesMasterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['CompanyName'].queryset = BranchesMaster.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Answer (score -3):

you have to make two classes in models.py

```
class Sales(models.model):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(User , on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    { add more attributes if u want } 

class Employee(models.model):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(User , on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    { add more attributes if u want }
```

after that make a new file named forms.py

```
   class SalesForm(forms.Modelform):
       class Meta:
       model = Sales
       fields = [ 'u can insert the fields which u want to show in ur form  ' ]
```

similarly you an make form class for your Employee

```
NOTE:--
u have to import ur model in your form.py module
and do import--- from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 in ur models.py file
```